# Overload extension method for multiple classes

Tags: c#, extension-methods, overloading

In my project I have a class that represents a certain document type. Each class has its own properties and methods although there are some similarities between them.

I am trying to implement an extension method for each class that has the same name (*method overloading*) but I am getting an ambiguous call error

Code to explain further

Document Type A class representation:

```
static class DocType_A
{
    private static XElement baseDocType_A = XmlFiles[0].Root;

    // Extension Method
    internal static IEnumerable<ViewData> AsViewData(this IEnumerable<XElement> result)
    {
        return
            from doc in result select new ViewData { };
    }


    // Contains methods for querying through the XML file of this [DocType_A] type
    internal static class Query
    {
        internal static IEnumerable<XElement> ByStatusOrAny(byte status = 0)
        {
            return baseDocType_A.Descendants("DocType_A").Select(doc => doc);
        }

        internal static IEnumerable<XElement> Expired()
        {
            return baseDocType_A.Descendants("DocType_A").Where("some conditions").Select(doc => doc);
        }

    }

    // Represents the data needed to be displayed to the user via the DGV
    internal class ViewData
    {
        // [DocType_A] related Property 
    }

    internal class Counter
    {
        // some property
    }

}
```

Document Type B class representation:

```
static class DocType_B
{
    private static XElement baseDocType_B = XmlFiles[1].Root;

    // Extension Method
    internal static IEnumerable<ViewData> AsViewData(this IEnumerable<XElement> result)
    {
        return
            from doc in result select new ViewData { };
    }


    // Contains methods for querying through the XML file of this [DocType_A] type
    internal static class Query
    {
        internal static IEnumerable<XElement> ByStatusOrAny(byte status = 0)
        {
            return baseDocType_B.Descendants("DocType_B").Select(doc => doc);
        }

        internal static IEnumerable<XElement> Expired()
        {
            return baseDocType_B.Descendants("DocType_B").Where("some conditions").Select(doc => doc);
        }

    }

    // Represents the data needed to be displayed to the user via the DGV
    internal class ViewData
    {
        // [DocType_B] related Property 
    }

    internal class Counter
    {
        // some property
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class SomeApplicationClass
{
    void Method()
    {
        IEnumerable<DocType_A.ViewData> query = DocType_A.Query.ByStatusOrAny().AsViewData();
    }

    void SomeOtherMethod()
    {
        IEnumerable<DocType_B.ViewData> query = DocType_B.Query.ByStatusOrAny().AsViewData();
    }
}
```

But I am getting ambiguous call error.

Is is possible to make extension method for each class with the same name?

[image: error]

Comment: What you are trying to do isn't possible because you are defining the same extension method in two different classes. The extension methods are exactly the same, why not just have one extension class with that method in it? It doesn't make sense to define extension methods inside the class you are extending anyway...

Comment: This is not exactly my strongest point, but it seems to me that you're attempting to define the Extension methods in *both* classes which causes the conflict. Usually I think Extension Methods are defined in their own class. Is there a reason you're using static classes for DocType_A and DocType_B? This isn't threadsafe of course, and you'll probably run into other difficulties unless there's a real good reason for this particular implementation.

Comment: @DavidZemens Indeed I am attempting to define extension methods in both classes as I thought at first that extension method will be class scoped. And for the reason I am making the DocType class static is due to my application logic as this represents a type of document not an instance of it or so I thought.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension methods that you are creating aren't for Doctype_A or Doctype_B, you are creating them for the IEnumerable < XElement >.  So you do actually have two extension methods with the same signature.

If you want one specific to A or B, you'd do it like this

```
    internal static IEnumerable<XElement> ByStatusOrAny(this DocType_A doc, byte status = 0)
    {
        return doc.Query.Descendants("DocType_A").Select(doc => doc);
    }
```

and then call it like

```
    DocType_A.ByStatusOrAny().AsViewData();
```

I know you want it to be scoped, but that's not how it works.  Whatever has the [this] qualifier is what the extension method is going to be applied to, regardless of the class it's in.  You *might* be able to do what you want if you keep each extension method in a different namespace and only reference the namespace you want in the specific files you want, but I've never tried that, so your mileage may very.

Also, as others have pointed out, your example doesn't seem to fit the normal use case for extension methods.  So if that's really what you are doing you might want to rework something.

Answer (score 0):

You are thinking about extension Methods as if they were class Methods. They are not.

What they actually are is syntax sugar for a bunch of static Methods, so the compiler & Intellisense can help you calling them.

You have to functions that require a parameter of type `IEnumerable<XElement>`. Wich one is the compiler suppsoed to call on a `IEnumerable<XElement>`? For all intents of overload checking, the "this" parameters is ignored. After after that you have two functions with the same name and with any parameter types to differentiate on.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your problem is here:

```
internal static IEnumerable<ViewData> AsViewData(this IEnumerable<XElement> result)
```

You have one metod like this in DocType_B and DocType_A ... if you remove static, it should work, but I don't think this is a way to go.

Comment: by definition, an extension method is a static method.